# Game engine sprite sheet performance issues - DrawImage srcRectangle performance issues

Tags: c#, graphics, game-engine

I'm trying to make a game engine, with a sprite sheet loading system. Originally it was based upon single images but I ran into huge memory issues which ultimately led to me using a sprite sheet system.

Before the change the engine was getting around 300+ frames per second rendering, with a render time of around 2ms. Now the render time is 16 - 20ms and the fps about 40. I've tried optimizing my code by reducing the amount of calculations being ran but it has barely improved it at all.

What could I do to optimize this, the source of my problem seems to be using a srcRectangle to select the area of the sprite sheet to display, with the DrawImage method.

Draw method:

```
public virtual void Draw(Graphics g)
{
   g.DrawImage(this.SpriteController.SpriteSheet,this.GetBoundingBox(), this.SpriteController.GetSpriteRectangle(),GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

GetBoundingBox method:

```
public Rectangle GetBoundingBox()
{
   return new Rectangle((int)this.X, (int)this.Y, this.SpriteController.Width, this.SpriteController.Height);
}
```

GetSpriteRectangle method:

```
public RectangleF GetSpriteRectangle()
{
   return new RectangleF(this.SpriteX, this.SpriteY, this.Width, this.Height);
}
```

That's all that is ran on render.

Comment: 1. There's any reason why you don't use XNA? Or monoGame? 2.What does this.SpriteController.SpriteSheet do? Are you sure you're not reloading the whole image at each frame?

Comment: 1. I'm writing my own to learn. Rest assured, if I was going to sell a game I would use a pre-made game engine.
2. It is a bitmap of the sprite sheet
3. Yes. The code there is literally everything being ran

Comment: Xna is not a game engine is a microsoft library that you can use to make games. It just gives you game related abstraction (for example textures) and a ready made game loop.

Comment: And most of all you're using libraries made to do GUI application that are probably not well suited to do a game. Xna instead wraps the directX library which are the library for multimedia and games.